# How to delete old custom-css-stuff in the customizer-live-preview?

Tags: theme-customizer

I have a problem in the **customizer**. I want to see the **live-preview** from the CSS **pseudo-elements** and **custom_css**, too. So I append the `<style>` in the `<head>` like this, in the *customizer.js*:

```
wp.customize( 'custom_css', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        $('head').append("<style>"+ newval + "</style>");  
    } );
} );
```

So every change, append the style in the head.

[image: <head>]

This is ok with the pseudo-elements, but when i delete the custom_css in the customizer: the change would be not remove.

How can I delete the old custom-css-stuff in the customizer-live-preview?

Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<style>` tag accepts all the global HTML attribute, including class and id. So, you could do something like this:

```
wp.customize( 'custom_css', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {

      if ( $("#my-custom-style").length > 0 ) {
        $("#my-custom-style").remove();
      }

      $('head').append("<style id="my-custom-style">"+ newval + "</style>");

    } );
} );
```

Comment: Thats great! I didn't know that i can use an id or class in a style-tag. Thank you so much cybmeta! I use your `$("#my-custom-style").remove();` on the beginning. So i have just one 'my-custom-style'-style tag in the header. :) 
`wp.customize( 'custom_css', function( value ) {
    value.bind( function( newval ) {
        if ( $("#my-custom-style").length > 0 ) {
         $("#my-custom-style").remove();
      } 
 $('head').append("<style id='my-custom-style'>"+ newval + "</style>");
    } );
} );`

Comment: Yeah, without the `else` is better.